# Image embedded inside html, but with image data not inline

Tags: html

Is there a ('newbie-simple') way to embed an image inside html, however not in the inline form as usual:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA [...]" />
```

but in a form where the base64 code is placed on the end of the html file?

A possible benefit of this method would be that an image can be inserted in the page on more than one place using the same image data from the bottom of the html file.

Comment: Is it more important for you to not waste traffic (having to load the image multiple times) or is the problem that you need multiple images to become the same image and want to do that in one position?

Comment: I would like to use the image on several places in different sizes etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5, then you do not have to worry about caches. The browser will load all images and store them into an image-list, therefore the image will be loaded only once and reused at every place the key (the URL to the source image) is found.

The only thing you will have to do, if you are only using HTML, is to copy the URL of the image into every place you need to use it. This is necessary, because you cannot declare variables in HTML and hence cannot change them from another place in the document. For this purpose you would need additionally javascript for example.

Then you can go ahead with CSS to adjust the pictures to your requirements. Yu can either define classes in the header and let the img tags have these classes, or you can type the style properties inline or you can import an external CSS-file.

EDIT:

An example with javascript would be to add this code in

```
<body>
  <img id="img" src="myIMG.jpg">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeImage(id, src) {
      document.getElementById(id).src=a;
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

Here the function changeImage is declared now. You can call this function either via onclick or inside of the script tag. You can address the correct image through its ID as first parameter (you will have to give every image its ID, don't confuse it with the image-list of your browser, here you define the ID in the img-tag) and the new source url as second parameter.

Comment: Hvala Ivo! Ok, how would work this in the simplest form in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: With pure HTML/CSS - unfortunately no.

I need that too for [Sciter Notes](https://notes.sciter.com/) project to save notes (plain HTML files) with embedded images.

Ideally you should be able to do something like this:

```
<img src="cid:1234" />
...
<data id=1234 type="image/png" base64>
  iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...
</data>
```

but unfortunately no such mechanism yet.

But you can implement schema explained above with script though.

Comment: For `<img>` the only solution is to use inline image data like in your question.